# JSON.stringify different from direct access to object property, strongloop

Tags: javascript, json, strongloop

I use strongloop to build my api.
On a particular route the query includes model's relations. I get an array of objects that I would like to arrange.
In this particular arranging function I face the following problem.
The function receive an object named "item" containing a "trans" field (this field is an array of another object).
this piece of code :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(item, null, 2));
```

produces this result :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "created": "2015-08-19T21:04:16.000Z",
  "updated": null,
  "authorid": 0,
  "likes": 0,
  "shares": 0,
  "fav": 0,
  "validated": 0,
  "comments": 0,
  "trans": [
    {
      "text": "Première question en français",
      "questionId": 1
    }
  ],
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "questionid": 1,
      "questionId": 1,
      "trans": [
        {
          "text": "q1 : reponse 1 en francais",
          "answerId": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "questionid": 1,
      "questionId": 1,
      "trans": [
        {
          "text": "q1 : reponse 2 en francais",
          "answerId": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This problem is when I try to reach this part :

```
item.trans[0].text
```

console says **"item.trans is undifined"** and when I try this piece of code :

```
console.log(item.trans);
```

I have this result :

```
function (condOrRefresh, options, cb) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      if (typeof f.value === 'function') {
        return f.value(self);
      } else if (self.__cachedRelations) {
        return self.__cachedRelations[name];
      }
    } else {
      if (typeof condOrRefresh === 'function'
        && options === undefined && cb === undefined) {
        // customer.orders(cb)
        cb = condOrRefresh;
        options = {};
        condOrRefresh = undefined;
      } else if (typeof options === 'function' && cb === undefined) {
        // customer.orders(condOrRefresh, cb);
        cb = options;
        options = {};
      }
      options = options || {}
      // Check if there is a through model
      // see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1076
      if (f._scope.collect &&
        condOrRefresh !== null && typeof condOrRefresh === 'object') {
        //extract the paging filters to the through model
        ['limit','offset','skip','order'].forEach(function(pagerFilter){
            if(typeof(condOrRefresh[pagerFilter]) !== 'undefined'){
                f._scope[pagerFilter] = condOrRefresh[pagerFilter];
                delete condOrRefresh[pagerFilter];
            }
        });
        // Adjust the include so that the condition will be applied to
        // the target model
        f._scope.include = {
          relation: f._scope.collect,
          scope: condOrRefresh
        };
        condOrRefresh = {};
      }
      return definition.related(self, f._scope, condOrRefresh, options, cb);
    }
  }
```

How can I simply access the "trans" property in this case to get the text inside ?
(Not really at easy in js)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your `item` object has implemented the [`toJSON` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior).

Pop open your browser's console and run this snippet to see an example of how this can make a difference between the stringified JSON and the actual object:

```js
var x = {

  name: "foo",

  children : function() {
    return [ { name: 'child 1' }, { name: 'child 2' } ];
  },
  
  toJSON: function() {
    var simplified = { name: this.name, children: this.children() };
    
    return simplified
  }

};

// shows children as a simple array
console.log( JSON.stringify( x, null, 2 ) );
// {
//   "name": "foo",
//   "children": [
//     {
//       "name": "child 1"
//     },
//     {
//       "name": "child 2"
//     }
//   ]
// }

// oops... not what you expected
console.log( x.children[0].name );
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Of course, the easiest fix would be to parse the stringify result:

```
var y = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( x ) );
console.log( y.children[0].name );
```

It's a last-case-scenario-type solution, though, since JSON.stringify is a very expensive function.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot ! That worked. I'll use it as a temporary workaround before I find a more effective solution.

Comment: @valvince did you find a better solution?